# Relative path in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, relative-path

I'm trying to insert a local image in my CSHTML file. The image is located in the same folder as the executable. I have tried the following, but none of these options work:

```
<img src="image.png" alt="Image" />
<img src="~/image.png" alt="Image" />
<img src="@Url.Content("~/image.png")" alt="Image" />
```

However, absolute paths and external URLs work perfectly:

```
<img src="C:/fake/path/image.png" alt="Image" />
<img src="www.example.com/image.png" alt="Image" />
```

This is how executing the app looks in cmd, I tried copying the same image to `C:`, `C:/API` and `C:/API/win-x64`, just in case, still nothing (there are no subfolders in `C:/API/win-x64`).

[image]

Does anyone know why is this happening? I don't want to use absolute paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access static files in the Asp.net core, you must place them in the wwwroot folder

[image]

According to the image above, the image link is as follows

```
<img src="/uploadedFiles/images/img_sample_five.jpg"  />
```

more information :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Thank you so much, you wouldn't believe the amount of time I spent looking for this answer. Now it seems to me that everyone gives for granted that everyone knows the wwwroot thing...